# Bokeh - How to use box tool without default selections?

Tags: select, preventdefault, bokeh

I have built a bokeh app that allows users to select windows in data and run python code to find and label (with markers) extreme values within these limits.  For ease of interaction, I use the box select tool for the range selection.  My problem arises when repeating this process for subsequent cases.  After markers are placed for the results, they are rendered invisible by setting alpha to zero and another case needs to be chosen.  When the new select box includes previous markers, they become visible based on the selection.  How do I override this default behavior?  Can markers be made unselectable? or can I add code to the customJS to hide them after they are selected?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible approaches. If you just want non-selected glyphs to "disappear" visually, you can set a policy to do that as described here:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#selected-and-unselected-glyphs

Basically, for `bokeh.plotting`, pass

```
nonselection_fill_alpha=0.0,
nonselection_line_alpha=0.0,
```

as arguments to your `plot.circle` call or whatever. Or if you are using the low level `bokeh.models` interface, something like:

```
renderer.nonselection_glyph = Circle(fill_alpha=0.0, line_alpha=0.0)
```

But be aware (I think you already are) that the invisible markers are still there, and still selectable if the user happens to draw a box over them with the selection tool.

If you truly want only a subset of the data to be visible and selectable after a selection, I'd say you want to replace the data in the column data source wholesale with the subset in your selection callback.